# fetch value from two fields (Date and Monetary) and convert it in text in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, field, odoo-15

I have two fields in Sale order, i need to get values from each one change its value in text and display in another field in custom model

Two fiedls in sale.order module:

```
amount_total = fields.Monetary(string="Total", store=True, compute='_compute_amounts', tracking=4)
```

```
date_order = fields.Datetime()
```

and this is my code so far:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

import random

readonly_fields_states = {
        state: [('readonly', True)]
        for state in {'sale', 'done', 'cancel'}
}

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    test = fields.Many2one(string="Test",
                       comodel_name='sale.order',
                       default=lambda x: random.randint(1, 10),
                       states=readonly_fields_states,
                       )



    @api.constrains('test')
    def check_test_length(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.test:
                if len(rec.test) > 50:
                    raise ValidationError('Длина текста строки "test" должна быть меньше 50 символов!')
            else:
                pass
```

The goal is: get data from fields turn its type into text and display that data in fiedl test when the two from sale.order is changed. For now i get only names S00001, S00002.. etc.

I have no working solution. I have tried various fucntion but non of them seems to work or i doing something wrong. I realise that my case bit unclear thats because i can`t wrap my head around it. So ask me whatever needed if you want to help.

Comment: Have you looked into using a [computed field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#computed-fields) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use odoo `related` field attribute.

In your `custom model` add a relational field with `sale.order` and then create related fields.

```
sale_order_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="sale.order")
sale_order_amount_total = fields.Monetary(related="sale_order_id.amount_total")
sale_order_date_order = fields.Datetime(related="sale_order_id.date_order")
```

Now in `custom model views` you'll be able to use created fields.

```
<field name="sale_order_amount_total" />
<field name="sale_order_date_order" />
```

Note that these fields will be directly related to your Many2one model instance (`sale.order record`)

Good practice is to set them to `readonly=True`

In case you are going to execute queries in your custom models using your related fields, you should consider using `store=True` as attribute.

For example

```
sale_order_amount_total = fields.Monetary(
  related="sale_order_id.amount_total",
  store=True,
  readonly=True
)
```